# Equivalent Current and Permeability of a Permanent Magnet

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electric-current

I'm trying to write down Maxwells equation for the vector poential around a bar magnet. Let's assume this is 2D crossection and the vector potential and all currents point out of the page, then $A$ can be treated as a scalar and Maxwells equation becomes:

$$\nabla\cdot \nu \,\nabla A=J$$

where $\nu$ is the inverse of $\mu$ an is in general a function of the $x,\,y$ coordinates and the value of the field at that point i.e $\|B\|=\|\nabla A\|$.

Outside the magnet we $\nu=1/\mu_0$ and $J=0$, but what goes on inside the magnet is what I'm trying to underdstand.

I know things can get very complicated with anisotropic materials and hysterysis, but I'm just looking for some simple functions to plug in for $J$ and $\nu$ that do well for a magnet not operating near its extreme.

If I assume a current sheet model where $J$ is only non zero along the edges of the magnet what kind of values for $J$ would be reasonable?

Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnet#Magnetic_moment) the average magnetization of a "good" bar magnet is $(100,000 \text{ to } 1000, 000) \text{ Am}^{-1}$ does that mean I can set $J=100,000\text{sgn}(x)\delta(|x|-w/2)$ assuming the magnet is centered on the origin, of width $w$ and magnetized in the $y$ direction.

If this is reasonable how can I treat the material inside magnet? I assume $J=0$, but do I need to use a relation for $\nu$ specific for the magnet? or perhaps a curve for the unmagnetized version of the same material will due since I've taken care of the magnetization with the current sheet.

Any suggestions are much appreciated. I'm really just looking for what I can plug into the FEM solver I've [implemented](https://github.com/tomginsberg/motorsim/tree/master/fealite) to produce some realistic results.

Thanks

Comment: With a bar magnet, you can think of the equivalent current as flowing around the outside of the bar.  The field will be the same as that of a similar solenoid.

Comment: @R.W.Bird Yah but I would like to extend this into a full model, i.e what is the magnitude of the equivalent current and what is the permeability of the material.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by full model, but if you know the magnitude of the field inside a bar magnet, then you can use the solenoid formula to calculate the equivalent current.

Comment: @R.W.Bird thanks thats a good start, but what would be a reasonable value for the field is approximately the remanence? Also what would be the permeability of the material be once you've transformed the magnet into a equivalent coil?